# When i started installing imagemagick i faced the problem which mentioned below?

Tags: 14.04

Please help me in resolving this issue:

```
Re-run: command not found
rank@rank-ThinkCentre-M73:/var/cache/sublime-text$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up sublime-text-installer (3083-1~webupd8~0) ...
cp: cannot stat ‘/var/cache/sublime-text/sublime_text_3/*’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package sublime-text-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @also note that imagemagick (which is already installed on  your system) probably has nothing to do with your problem, which is rather due to a borked sublime installation.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue right now is a broken `sublime-text-installer` installation.

You can try running `sudo dpkg --configure sublime-text-installer`.

If that doesn't work you might want to purge it from your system and try reinstalling it or just leaving it off it.

`sudo apt-get purge sublime-text-installer`